# Android: preserving activity/fragment state

Tags: android

If I want to keep track of an int value in an activity/fragment, is this approach incorrect:

In layout XML, have:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/int_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

On fragment's `onCreateView` or activity's `onCreate`, have the following code:

```
TextView intId = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.int_id);
intId.setText(String.valueOf(<integer_value_to_keep_track_of>));
```

Then, whenever I need to use the int value later in the code, access it by doing the following:

```
int accessId = Integer.valueOf(((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.detail_column_id)).getText().toString());
```

Something tells me this is not the best way to preserve state. Would declaring a class member (e.g. `private int accessId`) and assigning that be better? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you are inside `onCreateView()` you get a reference of the `View`s that are part of the `Fragment`'s `View` hierarchy only once when you inflate the layout. When you call `infalter.inflate()` a `View` instance is returned; the parent of the hierarchy. You can use that `View`'s `findViewById()` to get a reference of the `TextView`.

For example:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState) {         // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.me_layout, container,false);       
TextView intId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.int_id);              
return view;    
}
```

Then once you get the `TextView` reference you can simply do

```
String text = intId.getText().toString();
```

inside `onCreateView();`

Comment: What if I need to access `intId` outside of `onCreateView`? I only access it when the user makes a selection in the fragment. Before, I had `private int accessId` defined as class member and had that assigned. I see running into issues with that approach though if the fragment gets interrupted (e.g. a phone call is received).

Comment: You can save the `Fragment`'s state, and then recover it after the interruption.

Comment: So you're saying instead of using `TextView`, define a class variable `private int accessId`, assign it, and use that value later? And in `FragmentActivity`, implement `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Comment: I meant using `setRetainInstanceState(boolean);` inside the `Fragment`

Comment: How about this? In onCreateView() you can directly access the TextView, and outside the function you can access like `if (isVisible() ) { TextView intId = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.int_id) ... }`  If the fragment is not visible, you don't need to access the TextView.

Comment: OK, so is it better to store the int value in a `TextView` or in a private class member and use `setRetainInstanceState`?